# Delta table update ONLY whenever any record gets updated

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am having a databricks delta table created on data lake storage which holds data as shown below.

```
db_name table_name  location                    table_format    table_type  load_ts
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc     table1      dbfs:/mnt/abc/data/table1   delta           EXTERNAL    2022-09-14T18:48:02.859+0000
abc     table2      dbfs:/mnt/abc/data/table2   delta           EXTERNAL    2022-09-14T18:48:02.859+0000
xyz     table1      dbfs:/mnt/xyz/data/table1   delta           EXTERNAL    2022-09-14T18:48:02.859+0000
xyz     table2      dbfs:/mnt/xyz/data/table2   delta           EXTERNAL    2022-09-14T18:48:02.859+0000
xyz     table3      dbfs:/mnt/xyz/data/table3   delta           EXTERNAL    2022-09-14T18:48:02.859+0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I am running this script daily to overwrite the complete table in databrcicks.
But my requirement is, this records should update only if there is any change occurred on that particular record else leave it. If there is any new records, it has to be added.

For Ex: Below is the input data frame I get whenever I run the script.
[image]
There is a change for one of the record and one new record gets added. only updated record should get updated and new record should be added to the final table.
The output table is expected to be updated as below.
[image]

I tried delta merge option but it updates all matching record which is not expected.

I have to keep the load_ts untouched if there NO update/insertion of new record happens (This is to track the time when any update is happened to that record).  If any record is updated, ONLY it should update in target table.

Is there any way/logic to achieve this ?
Any leads Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking something like this:

```
%sql
    MERGE INTO LakeDb.DeltaUsers t
    USING vStagingUsers s 
        ON t.UserId = s.UserId
        WHEN MATCHED AND sha1(concat_ws(s.DisplayName, s.Reputation, s.LastAccessDate)) != sha1(concat_ws(t.DisplayName, t.Reputation, t.LastAccessDate))
        THEN UPDATE
            SET t.DisplayName = s.DisplayName,
                t.Reputation = s.Reputation,
                t.LastAccessDate = s.LastAccessDate
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
            INSERT (UserId, DisplayName, LastAccessDate, Reputation) VALUES (s.UserId, s.DisplayName, s.LastAccessDate, s.Reputation)
```

I used function `SHA1` here rather than `HASH` which is much less likely exposed to collisions.
Futhermore, `concat_ws` is used to concatenate values of selected columns. When list of the columns are exactly the same then you can use `concat_ws(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same thing in my environment its worked fine with the merge operation.

First of all, I create a sample Data frame and did a merge operation.

I have taken `sour`  as a target and `vv` as a source. Please follow below code:

**Code**:

```
%sql

MERGE INTO sour AS target
USING vv as source
 on target.location = source.location
 WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET 
 target.db_name = source.db_name,
 target.table_name = source.table_name,
 target.location = source.location,
 target.table_type = source.table_type,
 target.load_ts = source.load_ts
 
WHEN NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (target.db_name,target.table_name,target.location,target.table_format,target.table_type,target.load_ts) VALUES(source.db_name,source.table_name,source.location,source.table_format,source.table_type,source.load_ts)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned in question, merge option will update all the records which satisfies the condition, which is not expected. From the target table, only the new record should be added and ONLY the updated record from source should be updated in Target. Rest of the records should remain as it is including the load_ts.

Comment: add a subcondition to `when matched`